# Mongodb on Ubuntu 19.10. Authentication

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb on ubuntu 19.10 using `apt install mongodb`(because there's nothing in official documentation about ubuntu 19.10. It isn't supported or what?)
So, it installed mongodb v3.6.8 and I use `systemctl start mongodb` to run it BUT as I understand it mongodb command is deprecated and mongod should be used instead, am I right?
When I try `sudo systemctl start mongodb`, it is says "Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found."

All I want to do is to only allow authorized users to connect to db. But when I try adding `security: authorization: disabled` into /etc/mongodb.conf mongodb fails to start(As I understand it's because it only works for mongod.conf which I obviously don't have).

What should I do? How to make an auth connection using mongodb command?

Comment: There is currently no Ubuntu version 19.0, so I assume that you may be referring to version 19.04. Ubuntu 19.04 reached its end of support on January 23rd, 2020. Please consider modifying your question to refer to a supported version of Ubuntu, such as 18.04, 19.10 or 20.04.

Comment: yes, sorry, I meant 19.10

Answer (score 0):

I found it out

`sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf` and

1. add `auth = true`
2. add an IP you want to give access to to 'bind_ip' or change the value to '0.0.0.0' to give access to everyone (you obviously have to create admin user before that)